# jquery colorbox opening within parent <body>

Tags: jquery, colorbox

i have a weird issue (FF and IE8) - color box seems to be opening
within the parent page's body: http://bit.ly/e4wI8Y

any idea what the issue could be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ok - found the issue:

i simply forgot to add

```
rel="stylesheet"
```

in the link to the css file...

;)